# Did the devil reject God in heaven?

Tags: bible, sin, heaven, scriptures

God created the devil, and in heaven Satan went to war with Him, correct? Did Satan reject God?

Comment: @0x499602D2 You are sorely mistaken. Christianity has several denominations, sects, and cults. You may want to read a primer about the history of Christianity and the various denominations that categorize themselves in it.

Comment: Please review [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) when you get a chance.  @Anonymous is correct, there's a WIDE range of beliefs within Christianity.  This question needs to be narrowed down a bit to be truly answerable.

Answer (score 2):

There are two famous verses believed to record the history of Satan;

[Isaiah 14:12-15](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2014:12-15&version=NIV) and  [Ezekiel 28:12-18](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezekiel%2028:12-18&version=NIV).

> *Ezekiel 28:14-15 (NIV)* You were anointed as a **guardian cherub**,
>       for so I ordained you. You were on the holy mount of God;
>       you walked among the fiery stones. You were **blameless** in your ways
>       from the day you were created  **till wickedness was found in you**.

When God created the mighty Cherub (Satan), he was perfect. At first, he was not a devil nor was he called Satan. But later, wickedness was found in him, he became proud, violent and sinful. Then God threw him out of heaven.

**Did Satan reject God?** YES

> *Isaiah 14:12-15 (NIV)* How you have fallen from heaven, morning star, son of the dawn! You have been cast down to the earth, you who once
>   laid low the nations! You said in your heart, “I will ascend to the
>   heavens; I will raise my throne above the stars of God; I will sit
>   enthroned on the mount of assembly, on the utmost heights of Mount
>   Zaphon. I will ascend above the tops of the clouds; **I will make
>   myself like the Most High**.” But you are brought down to the realm of
>   the dead, to the depths of the pit.

Satan rejected the authority of God, the superiority of God and rejected his creator. Satan wanted to become like God, or superior to God and wanted to be worshiped like God which caused his downfall.

Answer (score 0):

From a Jehovah's Witness viewpoint, it is believed that, before the creation of everything, Jehovah God created Jesus, Satan, and other heavenly beings. In their view, Satan existed in heaven, before Satan became the devil.

Comment: Did he become the devil in heaven?

Comment: IIRC, Satan rebelled against God in heaven, exited heaven, and became the devil.